# Make Apache to listen in multiple IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, port, httpd.conf

I'm in a big LAN, which is behind a proxy/firewall
I'm working with an apache/php/mysql application, which is hosted in a small server besides my workstation. This server is connected to the LAN also and is behind the proxy:

The server has a local IP assigned: **10.64.x.x**
Also, this server has a public IP assigned (or redirected from within the proxy/firewall) which is: **200.41.x.x**

I can't access public IP from LAN, but I can ping to the public IP from outside the building

**How should I configure Apache to listen also for public IP and open the 80 port for people accessing from outside the building?**.
It is set now to **Listen 10.64.x.x:80**

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand what you are saying, but typically would just listen on 80 and tell the virtual hosts to listen on all IPs.  Something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might port forwarding kind of thing. If you forward port 80 on the firewall/lan to your internal ip I think that is all you should need to do.

Comment: I can't access firewall/proxy config. I guess the public IP is already forwarded to server's local IP because I can ping public IP from outside the building, but I guess Apache is missconfigured

Comment: That's the issue without access to the firewall or proxy I am not sure you can do this as port 80 on the public IP might be closed. Is the public IP you access definitely the server?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can ping the ip does not mean port 80 is being forwarded or open.  Try telneting to port 80 on the public ip and see if you can connect.